# React App shown diffrently in localhost and Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, sass

My react app looks differently in Heroku then on my computer. I can see in inspect that some of the definitions are different and being run over.
I guess something in my sass files is compiling differently, but not sure how to solve it?

here is screenshots of spesific element for example:
[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuFOH.png)
,[heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TQbW.png)

Comment: issue could be due to NODE_ENV, while building on heroku production build is run,
check your webpack config or any other tool which you are using to bundle your app

Comment: what's the difference, please try to be more specific, eg. you can upload screenshots or logs.

Comment: i have added pictures to show diffrences with a spesific element

Comment: It seems that you have different paths or setting on the local machine and server.
I see you are using sass, you should check you output.css file and directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 100% of your files are committed and pushed to Heroku
Maybe a style file is not committed and pushed